# Cohomology $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $M=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

(a) Show there is an isomorphism of abelian groups $H^2(M\oplus M,M)\cong M \oplus M\oplus M$, where $H^2$ denotes for the second cohomology group.

(b) Let $G=GL_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$ act on $M\oplus M$ as automorphisms in the natural way. Show that we have an action of $G$ on $Z^2(⊕,)$ given by $$(\alpha . f)(a_1,a_2)=f(a_1\alpha^{-1},a_2\alpha^{-1})$$ for each $\alpha \in G$, $a_i \in M\oplus M$ and $f\in Z^2(⊕,)$. Furthermore show this defines an action on $H^2(M\oplus M,M)$

(c) Calculate the orbits of G on $H^2(M\oplus M,M)$.

First of all I'm trying to explicitly find all 2-cocycles and 2-coboundries from $M\oplus M \times M\oplus M$ to $M$ and then find $Z^2$ and $H^2=Z^2/B^2$ but I don't see a straightforward way to do so.

Comment: You could use the Künneth formula for the cohomology of direct products with trivial action for (a). (b) is reasonably straightforward.

Comment: Using Kunneth formula, we can show (a) but we can't find the 2-cocylces explicitly . For part (c) I think we need to know the 2-cocycles.

Comment: You can find them explicitly, by just taking the $2$-cocycles defined by the three direct summands of $H^2(M \oplus M,M)$.